# React - How to manage state of child list items that show/hide a modal in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items and each item can be edited. If the edit is cancelled I'm showing a modal to confirm. Multiple items can be in edit mode at once. I had no issue doing this if the modal was inside the list item but my issue is that I have to use the modal that is inside the parent, so then I need to communicate back to the list and update the state of each item. I have created a quick example, it's not a modal but you can see the same issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-state-issue-gpnbvr

I am able to edit and then cancel but it only works once for each item.
My approach here might be totally off so please bear with me :-)
Appreciate if anyone can provide some guidance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I undertand is if you try to close the opened edited item second+ time, it does not close, right?

I think `cancelledEditItemId` is not changing and because of which `useEffect` is not getting triggered. If you simply refresh the `cancelledEditItemId` on click of edit, it should work. I've made the respective changes in you `app.js` below:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export const ListItem = ({
  item,
  cancelHandler,
  cancelledEditItemId,
  refreshCancelledId
}) => {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (item.id === cancelledEditItemId) {
      setEditMode(false);
    }
  }, [item.id, cancelledEditItemId]);

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      {!editMode && <div>Test {item.id}</div>}
      {editMode && (
        <div>
          <input onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
      )}
      {!editMode && (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setEditMode(true);
            refreshCancelledId();
          }}
        >
          Edit
        </button>
      )}
      {editMode && (
        <>
          <button onClick={() => cancelHandler(item.id)}>Cancel</button>
          <button>Confirm</button>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const listItems = [
    { id: 1, text: "123" },
    { id: 2, text: "456" },
    { id: 3, text: "789" }
  ];
  const [showConfirmation, setShowConfirmation] = useState(false);
  const [editedItemId, setEditedIemId] = useState("");
  const itemRef = useRef("");

  const cancelHandler = (id) => {
    setShowConfirmation(true);
    itemRef.current = id;
  };

  const refreshCancelledId = () => {
    setEditedIemId(-1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {listItems.map((item) => (
        <ListItem
          item={item}
          cancelHandler={cancelHandler}
          cancelledEditItemId={editedItemId}
          refreshCancelledId={refreshCancelledId}
        />
      ))}

      {showConfirmation && (
        <>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "300px",
              height: "300px",
              backgroundColor: "#ccc",
              postion: "absolute",
              left: "50%",
              top: "50%"
            }}
          >
            Do you really want to cancel?
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setShowConfirmation(false);
                  setEditedIemId(itemRef.current);
                }}
              >
                Yes
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => {}}>No</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes I knew useEffect was not working and tried other things but did not work, Your code works thankyou!